# How do I turn a hex string directly into a byte array?

Tags: java, hex, arrays

I want to convert a string into hex, then into a byte array. Here is my code so far:

```
public static void findKey(){

    Cipher cipher;
    SecretKeySpec key;
    byte [] keyBytes;
    byte [] pt;
    byte [] ct;

    String plaintext = "Plaintxt";
    ct = new byte [] {(byte)0x4A, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x37, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0xB3};
    String ptHex = asciiToHex(plaintext);
    System.out.println(ptHex);
    pt = ptHex.getBytes();
    printByteArray(pt);
}
```

My method to convert to hex works fine, but when I use `getBytes`, it obviously turns it to 16 bytes which is not what I want. That was just an attempt. Here is the output from just printing my string to make sure it worked and then printing the byte array which is incorrect:

```
506c61696e747874
[  35  30  36  63  36  31  36  39  36  65  37  34  37  38  37  34  ]
-------------Key  Found-------------
```

I want to take the 50, the 6c, the 61 etc., and put it into a byte array like I did for ct like 0x50, 0x6c, and so on.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
byte[] getBytes(String s) {
    byte[] a = new byte[s.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = Byte.parseByte(s.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You sir truely are the man. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

it might help you

```
Byte.parseByte(string, 16);
```

check [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

also check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one-liner, which employs the JDK's API:

```
byte[] array = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(Long.parseLong(chars, 16)).array();
```

---

Here's a test:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String chars= "506c61696e747874";
    byte[] array = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(Long.parseLong(chars, 16)).array();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[80, 108, 97, 105, 110, 116, 120, 116]
```

Of course the output here is in decimal, but the values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simple java method for converting hex to byte array:

```
byte[] byteArray= new BigInteger(hexvalue, 2).toByteArray();
```